# Method "id" for object "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" does not exist in AppBundle:Game:view.html.twig at line 26

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

So, I'm trying to display all of the comments belonging to a game, but for some reason, I always get this error:

```
Method "id" for object "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" does not exist in AppBundle:Game:view.html.twig at line 26
```

The  getCommentsForGame looks like this

```
public function getCommentsForGame($game)
{
  $id = $game->getId();

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('game')

        ->select(
            'game.id',
            'game.title',
            'comments.id',
            'comments.content'
        )
        ->innerJoin('game.comments', 'comments')
        ->where('game.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

And then the Comment Entity:

```
/**
 * Id.
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(
 *     type="integer",
 *     nullable=false,
 *     options={
 *         "unsigned" = true
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 *
 * @var integer $id
 */
private $id;

/**
 * Get id.
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Games array
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Game", inversedBy="games")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="game_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * )
 *
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $games
 */
 protected $games;
```

And Game Entity:

```
/**
 * Comments array
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *      targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Comment",
 *    mappedBy="games"
 * )
 */
protected $comments;
```

In Twig I'm using this:

```
       {{ game.comments.id }}
```

Where's my error?

Comment: Does your Game Entity have an $id attribute? If yes, is it public? If no, is there a getter (getId()) for it?

Comment: What are you calling at line 26 in your `AppBundle:Game:view.html.twig` file?

Comment: Yes, I do have attribute $id and getter. I edited my post to show this and the twig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`game.comments` is returning a Collection and a collection doesn't have an ID. You have to loop through the Collection and get the ID for each Comment:

```
{% for comment in game.comments %}
    {{ comment.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

Try using `dump()` on `game.comments` and `game.comments[0]` to see what I mean.

Comment: Thank you, it does solve the problem, but now, although the site doesn't return any error message, no comments are shown and the array taken from getCommentsForGame seems to be empty. Do you have any idea why this may be?

Comment: Have there already been comments made? :-) It might also have something to do with your query. I don't think the INNER JOIN is what you need. What is the reason you've written your own method for this? Doctrines standard repository has support for relations out of the box.

Comment: Sadly, yeah :D And yes, I do believe it has to be something with query. I'll work on it and I'll research this support for relations deeper, if you say that they will suffice. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set strict_variables: false in the twig config
This fixed my issue